# Substitutions and simplifications in PDEs.

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, substitution

I have, e.g. a following PDE:

$\dfrac{\partial A}{\partial t} \:=\: -\,\dfrac{\partial\left(u\cdot A\right)}{\partial z}$

where

$A = \dfrac{B C}{D E}$,

where $B,\, C,\, D = f\left(t,\,z\right) \neq \rm const.$, but $E = \rm const.$, $u = f\left(t,\,z\right) \neq \rm const.$ is a velocity.

How do I substitute $A = \big(BC\big)\big/\big(DE\big)$ to the original PDE. I expect that (this is not a correct mathematical expression, but just to document my thinking):

$\partial A = \dfrac{1}{E} \cdot \partial\left(\dfrac{BC}{D}\right)$,

but I struggle to separate $B, C$ and $D$ to a single derivative terms.

Comment: I can tell that if the functions are all dependent on t then we can assert that $A = \mathrm{const}$ so we can state that $\frac{BC}{D} = \lambda $ but it is undefined at the moment to solve for all the functions.

Comment: I hope that I managed to describe my problem correctly. Variables $C$ and $D$ would be solved in another equation, while this one would be used to numerically solve $B$. Actually, in my PDEs, all the variables are also dependent on the axial (positional) coordinate $z$. To document this, I extended my post with a well-known convection term, however, I wanted to keep the post as simple as possible, just to understand the PDEs simplifications correctly.

Comment: What is $u$ in your equation $\dfrac{\partial A}{\partial t} \:=\: -\,\dfrac{\partial\left(u\cdot A\right)}{\partial z}$. Is it a parameter  falling from the sky ?

Comment: I hope not... :) $u$ is a velocity, sorry. It wasn't in my original post, I edited the post in relation to my previous comment (originally, the right side was just $0$), the velocity $u$ is a part of every convection term as I mentioned in the comment.

Comment: What do you mean with the symbol $\partial$ in the equation $\partial A = \dfrac{1}{E} \cdot \partial\left(\dfrac{BC}{D}\right)$ ? If it is a symbol for partial derivative, then it is the partial derivative with regard to which variable $t$ or $z$ ?

Comment: @JJacquelin I tried to explain in the post that this is not mathematically correct $\rightarrow$ just my thoughts how the substitution should be used. By this term I mean that if I am about to susbtitute $A$, all the variables that are not constant and are function of $t$ and $z$ such as $A$ is, must be put inside a partial derivative, i.e. $\partial$, term. My issue is with the simplification afterwards and separation of $B$, $C$ and $D$ to a single partial derivatives terms. All of those variables $B, C, D = f\left(t,z\right)$ as described in the post.

Comment: Is it that what you want  : $$\partial A =\frac{C}{ED}\partial B+\frac{B}{ED}\partial C-\frac{BC}{ED^2}\partial D$$ All seems non-sens.

Comment: @JJacquelin If it is correct then yes, thank you. How did you obtain $D^2$ in the last term? How would a substitution of $A = \dfrac{BC}{DE}$ in the original equation: \begin{equation}\dfrac{\partial A}{\partial t} \:=\: -\,\dfrac{\partial\left(u\cdot A\right)}{\partial z}\end{equation}
 look like? Thanks

Comment: Don't you know that the derivative of a function $\frac{1}{f(x)}$ is $-\frac{f'(x)}{(f(x))^2}$ ?

Comment: Have you never heard anything about "chain rule" of differentiation ?

Comment: I do not understand your point. No, I have not seen the use of a chain rule in the equation, otherwise I would not have asked... Nvm, thanks for answers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\dfrac{\partial A}{\partial t} \:=\: -\,\dfrac{\partial\left(u A\right)}{\partial z}$$

$$\dfrac{\partial  \dfrac{B C}{D E}}{\partial t} \:=\: -\,\dfrac{\partial\left(  \dfrac{u B C}{D E}\right)}{\partial z}$$
Since $E$=constant :
$$\dfrac{\partial  \dfrac{B C}{D}}{\partial t} \:=\: -\,\dfrac{\partial\left(  \dfrac{u B C}{D}\right)}{\partial z}$$

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule

$$\dfrac{C}{D}\dfrac{\partial B}{\partial t} + \dfrac{B}{D}\dfrac{\partial C}{\partial t} + BC\dfrac{\partial \frac{1}{D}}{\partial t}\:=-\dfrac{BC}{D}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial z} -\dfrac{uC}{D}\dfrac{\partial B}{\partial z} - \dfrac{uB}{D}\dfrac{\partial C}{\partial z} - uBC\dfrac{\partial \frac{1}{D}}{\partial z}$$
$\frac{\partial \frac{1}{D}}{\partial t}=-\frac{1}{D^2}\frac{\partial D}{\partial t}$

$$\dfrac{C}{D}\dfrac{\partial B}{\partial t} + \dfrac{B}{D}\dfrac{\partial C}{\partial t} - \frac{BC}{D^2}\frac{\partial D}{\partial t}\:=-\dfrac{BC}{D}\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial z} -\dfrac{uC}{D}\dfrac{\partial B}{\partial z} - \dfrac{uB}{D}\dfrac{\partial C}{\partial z} + \frac{uBC}{D^2}\frac{\partial D}{\partial z}$$

Comment: In the second term on the right side of the final equation, shouldn't there be: \begin{equation} -\: \dfrac{uC}{D}\dfrac{\partial B}{\partial z} \end{equation}?

Comment: If I may have one more question, is it possible to separate a following expression: \begin{equation} \dfrac{\partial A}{\partial z} \cdot \dfrac{\partial B}{\partial z}\:, \end{equation} where $A = f\left(z\right)$ and $B = f\left(z\right)$ to a terms with only a single partial derivative with respect to $z$. I looked at product rules as this is not a chain rule, in my opinion, and none of them answered my question.

Comment: You are right $u$ was missing. This is corrected now. To the second question : No, its not possible to separate the product of the two partial derivatives.

Comment: Thanks for the provided solution above as well as the correction. As for the second question, I was kind of leaning towards this assumption, but just want to be sure :).